std::shared_ptr destructing even when a reference of it exists
I am using boost::asio and c++20 coroutines in my own socket/network library. I have a server class that creates a shared_ptr to a session class on accept, and holds the session in a set. The socket continually async reads like this:
void Socket::read(const String &delim) {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(_sock, boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(_recBuf), delim,
    boost::asio::bind_executor(_readStrand,
    [this, delim = delim, self = shared_from_this()] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes) {
        // LOGIC FOR HANDLING THE READ ...
        Socket::handleMsg(<the msg>);
        Socket::read(delim);
    }));
}

void Socket::doWrite(std::shared_ptr<String> str) {
    asio::async_write(_sock, asio::buffer(*str),
    asio::bind_executor(_writeStrand,
    [this, str, self = shared_from_this()] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, const std::size_t bytes) {
        // LOGIC TO HANDLE WRITE
        // WILL EITHER POP NEXT MESSAGE OFF QUEUE OR EXIT
    }));
}

The message handling occurs here:
bool Socket::handleMsg(const object::String &msg) {
    try {
        auto self = shared_from_this();
        co_spawn(_asyncHandleMsgStrand, [this, self, m] () -> boost::asio::awaitable<void> {
            try {
                co_await handleMsgInt(m);
            }
            catch (const std::exception &e) {
                lh.e(fmt::format("{:s}", e.what()));
                stop_int();
            }
        },
        [this, self] (std::exception_ptr e) {
            if (e) {
                _ioc.post([e, self] {
                    std::rethrow_exception(e);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        lh.e(fmt::format("{:s}", e.what()));
        stop_int();
        return false;
    }
 
    return true;
}

The issue is that after handling a message that causes a co_await to suspend in handleMsgInt(), on destruction of the coroutine lambda in handleMsg() the self shared_ptr destructs. In the destructor I check if the server reference still exists, and it does, but the use_count() method returns 0.
Something else that I encountered that may just be lack of knowledge on my part is that after creation of the session here:
inline static std::shared_ptr<Socket> create(boost::asio::io_context &ioc, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &sock, Server &server) {
      return std::shared_ptr<Socket>(new Socket(ioc, sock, server));
   }

I log the address of this (inside the constructor of Socket), the resulting shared_ptr.get() address, and shared_from_this().get() address. These three addresses are different. Socket inherits from a base class which in turn inherits from enable_shared_from_this. I don't know if that affects anything.
(2024/05/31 18:19:02.775665476) <aaaf> (trace)   Socket: this: 0x7fffe8001000
(2024/05/31 18:19:02.775706976) <aaaf> (trace)   Server: shared_ptr before adding to sessions set: 0x7fffe8001150, ref: 1
(2024/05/31 18:19:02.775727176) <aaaf> (trace)   Server: shared_ptr after adding to sessions: 0x7fffe8001150, ref: 2
(2024/05/31 18:19:02.775739376) <aaaf> (trace)   Server: sessions.begin()->get(): 0x7fffe8001150, ref: 2
(2024/05/31 18:19:02.775747376) <aaaf> (trace)   Server: shared from this: 0x7fffe8001218, ref: 3

I understand that this is not a whole lot of information to go off of, I guess I am looking for some obvious errors or things to keep in mind.
Forgot to include that the socket class has virtual diamond inheritance to the base class that inherits from enable_shared_from_this. I don't know if that changes the behaviour.
=== EDIT ===
So thanks everyone for the input. The issue ended up being something I don't quite understand. If you look in the handleMsg method, you can see the I co_spawn using a lambda and pass shared_from_this() in the capture. I have been pulling my hair out for trying everything, so removed the call to shared_from_this() and stopped passing the reference in the capture. This actually fixed the problem, and I know it did because the bug was extremely reliably reproducible. Every time I followed a certain sequence of inputs it would happen before.
Is this a bug in my code? Probably. Is it related to this or this, I don't know.
Anyway, if anyone runs into this issue, maybe this will help.

Offtopic: Please use std::make_shared<Socket>(ioc, sock, server);, not std::shared_ptr<Socket>(new Socket(ioc, sock, server));!

I would like to use make_shared, but I private the constructor to force new objects to be created as shared_ptr. Would this be part of my problem?

@bustus_primus You must use make_shared() when using enable_shared_from_this, as it sets up shared_from_this to work properly. You might try making make_shared() be a friend of Socket, but rather than using a private constructor, you could instead make the public constructor take a private type as input, and then provide a public static method that calls make_shared() passing in that type to the constructor. There is an example of this on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

I'm not sure that this is the case. I cannot find anything referencing enable_shared_from_this requiring make_shared. Could you provide a link to resource with an explanation of this? Thanks for your reply either way, I appreciate it. Also, I'm not quite sure how to implement your solution to the private constructor issue. Could you provide an example?

@bustus_primus See my previous comment for a link to an example for the private constuctor issue. As for the enable_shared_from_this issue, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared "The std::shared_ptr constructor called by this function enables shared_from_this with a pointer to the newly constructed object of type T"

You can use passkey idiom to protect public constructor from using outside of class.

It doesn't need to be created with make_shared,  it just needs to be managed by a shared_ptr (one must be created)

@bustus_primus the enable_shared_from_this link above provides an example of the passkey idiom that Marek mentioned.

Are you doing something more complex in constructor of your Socket? Maybe there you are creating a problem there. Or maybe you have two independent set of shared_ptr?

@MarekR see my updated comment about diamond virtual inheritance on the socket class. And no, in the constructors of the whole inheritance tree nothing interesting happens.

"check if the server reference still exists" what does this mean?

@RemyLebeau thanks for pointing me to that. To be honest, I don't really understand it. Does the struct hold all the class members? Is it a proxy for the class?

@JeffGarrett The session has access to the server, so in the destructor I look at the set of sessions to see if the shared_ptr to it still exists.

Did a test with make_shared and still have the same issue.

@RemyLebeau there is absolutely no obligation to use make_shared for shared_from_this to work

I would like to use make_shared, but I private the constructor to force new objects to be created as shared_ptr. Would this be part of my problem?  Where in the code provided do you do this private constructor?  A [mcve] would be most helpful.

Out on a limb, perhaps you are using std::make_shared with boost::enable_shared_from_this or vice versa. Without the relevant code this question can never be answered. Regardless, with c++20 coroutines, why the need for shared pointers?

Oh, and did you remember to make the base public

@Eljay you should make a question on stack overflow with a [mre], there'll be something else going wrong

@sehe look at my recent edit for the "solution" if youre still interested
